# Image not refresh after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have weird problem, I upload image this way :

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var row = MainUserGridView.SelectedRow;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[0].Text)) return;

            var id = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text);

            var filePath = Server.MapPath("~//Upload");

            if (!Directory.Exists(filePath + "//user" + id + "//gfx"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath + "//user" + id + "//gfx");

            if (FileUploadControl.FileName.ToLower().Contains(".jpg"))
            {
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(filePath + "//user" + id + "//gfx//photoInst.jpg");

            }
            photoInst.ImageUrl = "~/Upload/user" + id + "/gfx/photoInst.jpg";
            StatusLabel.Text = "File uploaded!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

and photoInst which is image isn't refreshed. But when I hit f5 then image will be refreshed. Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the browser is caching the image. For a ghetto fix, you can add a query string to the image reference with the timestamp.

```
photoInst.ImageUrl = "~/Upload/user" + id + string.Format("/gfx/photoInst.jpg?{0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

See if that works for you.

Good luck!

Comment: With this solution, I have to put always the ticks?